Using clang and trying to generate a visual studio solution with premake doesn't compile with "llvm-lib.exe exited with code 1"
I have 2 premake files 1 for my renderer, and one for my engine but when I generate a vs2022 solution via the command premake5 vs2022 trying to build said solution hits me with a 
I would like to know why this behavior happens, as building on the command line (with gmake) works perfectly fine, and being able to build in VS would greatly increase the productivity of debugging
Here are the aforementioned solution files
workspace "Wrenderer"
configurations { "Debug", "Release"}
project "Wrenderer"
    language "C"
    targetname "Wrenderer"
    architecture "x64"
    kind "StaticLib"
    outputdir = "%{cfg.system}-%{cfg.architecture}/%{cfg.buildcfg}"

    toolset "clang"
    cdialect "C99"

    targetdir("%{wks.location}/Binaries/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    objdir("%{wks.location}/Binaries/Intermediates/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    files { "include/**.h", "src/**.c" }
    libdirs { "./libs/" }
    includedirs { "./include/" }
    includedirs { "./include/libs/" }
    includedirs { os.getenv("VULKAN_SDK") .. "/Include" }
    buildoptions { "-Wextra -Wall" }
    links { "vulkan-1", "glfw3" }
    removefiles { "test/**.**" }
    filter "configurations:Debug"
        defines { "DEBUG" }
        symbols "On"
    filter ""
    filter "configurations:Release"
        optimize "On"
    filter ""
    filter "system:windows"
        links { "user32", "msvcrt", "gdi32", "shell32", "libcmt" }
        defines { "VK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR" }
    filter ""
    filter "system:linux"
        defines { "VK_USE_PLATFORM_XLIB_KHR" }
    filter ""
    filter "action:gmake"
        prebuildcommands {

            "mkdir -p" .. " %[%{wks.location}/Binaries/]",
            "mkdir -p" .. " %[%{wks.location}/Binaries/Intermediates/]",

            "mkdir -p" .. " %[%{wks.location}/Binaries/" .. outputdir .. "]",
            "mkdir -p" .. " %[%{wks.location}/Binaries/Intermediates/" .. outputdir .. "]",
        }
    filter ""
    filter "not action:gmake"
        prebuildcommands {

            "{MKDIR}" .. " %[%{wks.location}/Binaries/]",
            "{MKDIR}" .. " %[%{wks.location}/Binaries/Intermediates/]",

            "{MKDIR} %[%{wks.location}/Binaries/" .. outputdir .. "]",
            "{MKDIR} %[%{wks.location}/Binaries/Intermediates/" .. outputdir .. "]",
        }
    filter ""
    project "WrenTest"
        architecture "x64"
        kind "ConsoleApp"  
        language "C"   

        files { "**.h", "test/**.c" }
        outputdir = "%{cfg.system}-%{cfg.architecture}/%{cfg.buildcfg}"

        toolset "clang"
        cdialect "C99"
    
        targetdir("%{wks.location}/Binaries/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
        objdir("%{wks.location}/Binaries/Intermediates/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

        libdirs { "./libs/" }
        includedirs { "./include/" }
        includedirs { "./include/libs/" }
        includedirs { os.getenv("VULKAN_SDK") .. "/Include" }
        links { "Wrenderer" }
        buildoptions { "-Wextra -Wall" }
        links { "vulkan-1", "glfw3" }

        filter "configurations:Debug"
            defines { "DEBUG" }
            symbols "On"
            sanitize { "Address", "Fuzzer" }
        filter ""
        filter "configurations:Release"
            optimize "On"
        filter ""
        filter "system:windows"
            links { "user32", "msvcrt", "gdi32", "shell32", "libcmt" }
            defines { "VK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR" }
        filter ""
        filter "system:linux"
            defines { "VK_USE_PLATFORM_XLIB_KHR" }
        filter ""
newaction {
    trigger     = "clean",
    description = "clean the software",
    execute     = function ()
       print("Cleaning")
       os.rmdir("./Binaries")
       os.remove("./Lib/*.lib")
       os.remove("*.make")
       os.remove("Makefile")
       os.remove("*.vcxproj")
       os.remove("*.vcxproj.filters")
       os.remove("*.vcxproj.user")
       os.remove("*.sln")
       print("done.")
    end
}

and the one for the engine
workspace "Wrenderer"
project "Wrengine"
    language "C"
    targetname "Wrengine"
    architecture "x64"
    outputdir = "%{cfg.system}-%{cfg.architecture}/%{cfg.buildcfg}"
    kind "ConsoleApp"
    toolset "clang"
    cdialect "C99"

    targetdir("%{wks.location}/Binaries/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    objdir("%{wks.location}/Binaries/Intermediates/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    files { "include/**.h", "src/**.c" }
    libdirs { "./libs/" }
    includedirs { "./include/" }
    includedirs { "./Wrenderer/include/" }
    includedirs { "./include/libs/" }
    includedirs { os.getenv("VULKAN_SDK") .. "/Include" }
    libdirs { os.getenv("VULKAN_SDK") .. "/Lib" }
    buildoptions { "-Wextra -Wall" }
    links { "vulkan-1", "glfw3" }
    links { "Wrenderer" }

    filter "configurations:Debug"
        defines { "DEBUG" }
        symbols "On"
        sanitize {"Address"}
    filter ""
    filter "configurations:Release"
        optimize "On"
    filter ""
    filter "system:windows"
        links { "user32", "msvcrt", "gdi32", "shell32", "libcmt" }
        defines { "VK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR" }
    filter ""
    filter "system:linux"
        defines { "VK_USE_PLATFORM_XLIB_KHR" }
    filter ""
    filter "action:gmake"
    filter ""

    prebuildcommands {
        "compileShaders.bat"
    }
include "Wrenderer/premake5.lua"

my file tree looks like so

from what I've been messing around with it sort of looks like its trying to force the msvc c standard on it, which might contribute to the issue, but still evades me

the question is not about programming, but about the tool. can you edit the tags?

Try to terminate filters by filter "" to reset filter, especially when you have other commend afterward (as include which will begin with the last filter).

From https://premake.github.io/docs/Tokens/#path-in-commands, paths in prebuild commands should be surrounded by %[..]; {MKDIR} should work for both BTW, --shell=cmd/--shell=posix might help.

What is the full error message (from output panel), the one from error panel is mostly a resume.

Which version of premake5 do you use?

@Jarod42 the latest version

@Jarod42 here is the full message from the output panel
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1544,5): error MSB6006: "llvm-lib.exe" exited with code 1.

@Jarod42 I have implemented the filter "", and the %[] changes you recommended, --shell did not seem to work at all, giving invalid option when trying to provide it like so
premake5.exe --shell=posix gmake as well as premake5.exe gmake --shell=posix
I will be updating the post accordingly

The answer was just to suck it up and switch to msvc for the vs2022 profile
workspace "Wrenderer"
configurations { "Debug", "Release"}
project "Wrenderer"
    language "C"
    targetname "Wrenderer"
    architecture "x64"
    kind "StaticLib"
    outputdir = "%{cfg.system}-%{cfg.architecture}/%{cfg.buildcfg}"

    cdialect "C99"

    targetdir("%{wks.location}/Binaries/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    objdir("%{wks.location}/Binaries/Intermediates/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    files { "include/**.h", "src/**.c" }
    libdirs { "./libs/" }
    includedirs { "./include/" }
    includedirs { "./include/libs/" }
    includedirs { os.getenv("VULKAN_SDK") .. "/Include" }
    links { "vulkan-1", "glfw3" }
    removefiles { "test/**.**" }
    filter "configurations:Debug"
        defines { "DEBUG" }
        symbols "On"
    filter ""
    filter "configurations:Release"
        optimize "On"
    filter ""
    filter "system:windows"
        defines { "VK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR" }
    filter ""
    filter "system:linux"
        defines { "VK_USE_PLATFORM_XLIB_KHR" }
    filter ""
    filter "action:gmake"
    prebuildcommands {

        "mkdir -p" .. " %[%{wks.location}/Binaries/]",
        "mkdir -p" .. " %[%{wks.location}/Binaries/Intermediates/]",

        "mkdir -p" .. " %[%{wks.location}/Binaries/" .. outputdir .. "]",
        "mkdir -p" .. " %[%{wks.location}/Binaries/Intermediates/" .. outputdir .. "]",
    }
    filter "not action:gmake"
        prebuildcommands {

            "{MKDIR}" .. " %[%{wks.location}/Binaries/]",
            "{MKDIR}" .. " %[%{wks.location}/Binaries/Intermediates/]",

            "{MKDIR} %[%{wks.location}/Binaries/" .. outputdir .. "]",
            "{MKDIR} %[%{wks.location}/Binaries/Intermediates/" .. outputdir .. "]",
        }
    filter ""
    filter "action:gmake"
    toolset "clang"
    buildoptions {"-Wextra", "-Wall"}

    filter "not action:gmake"
    toolset "msc"
    filter""

project "WrenTest"
        architecture "x64"
        kind "ConsoleApp"  
        language "C"   

        files { "**.h", "test/**.c" }
        outputdir = "%{cfg.system}-%{cfg.architecture}/%{cfg.buildcfg}"

        cdialect "C99"
    
        targetdir("%{wks.location}/Binaries/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
        objdir("%{wks.location}/Binaries/Intermediates/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

        libdirs { "./libs/" }
        includedirs { "./include/" }
        includedirs { "./include/libs/" }
        includedirs { os.getenv("VULKAN_SDK") .. "/Include" }
        links { "Wrenderer" }
        links { "vulkan-1", "glfw3" }

        filter "configurations:Debug"
            defines { "DEBUG" }
            symbols "On"
        filter ""
        filter "configurations:Release"
            optimize "On"
        filter ""
        filter "system:windows"
            defines { "VK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR" }
        filter ""
        filter "system:linux"
            defines { "VK_USE_PLATFORM_XLIB_KHR" }
        filter ""

        filter "action:gmake"
        toolset "clang"
        buildoptions {"-Wextra", "-Wall"}
        links { "user32", "msvcrt", "gdi32", "shell32", "libcmt" }
        filter "not action:gmake"
        toolset "msc"
        filter ""
newaction {
    trigger     = "clean",
    description = "clean the software",
    execute     = function ()
       print("Cleaning")
       os.rmdir("./Binaries")
       os.remove("./Lib/*.lib")
       os.remove("*.make")
       os.remove("Makefile")
       os.remove("*.vcxproj")
       os.remove("*.vcxproj.filters")
       os.remove("*.vcxproj.user")
       os.remove("*.sln")
       print("done.")
    end
}

workspace "Wrenderer"
project "Wrengine"
    language "C"
    targetname "Wrengine"
    architecture "x64"
    outputdir = "%{cfg.system}-%{cfg.architecture}/%{cfg.buildcfg}"
    kind "ConsoleApp"
    cdialect "C99"

    targetdir("%{wks.location}/Binaries/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    objdir("%{wks.location}/Binaries/Intermediates/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    files { "include/**.h", "src/**.c" }
    libdirs { "./libs/" }
    includedirs { "./include/" }
    includedirs { "./Wrenderer/include/" }
    includedirs { "./include/libs/" }
    includedirs { os.getenv("VULKAN_SDK") .. "/Include" }
    libdirs { os.getenv("VULKAN_SDK") .. "/Lib" }
    links { "vulkan-1", "glfw3" }
    links { "Wrenderer" }

    filter "configurations:Debug"
        defines { "DEBUG" }
        symbols "On"
    filter ""
    filter "configurations:Release"
        optimize "On"
    filter ""
    filter "system:windows"
        defines { "VK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR" }
    filter ""
    filter "system:linux"
        defines { "VK_USE_PLATFORM_XLIB_KHR" }
    filter ""

    prebuildcommands {
        "compileShaders.bat"
    }

    filter "action:gmake"
    toolset "clang"
    links { "user32", "msvcrt", "gdi32", "shell32", "libcmt" }
    buildoptions {"-Wextra", "-Wall"}
    filter "not action:gmake"
    toolset "msc"
    filter ""

include "Wrenderer/premake5.lua"

